# Is there a Work around for <EOF> Error in XQuery with WSO2?

Tags: windows, wso2, xquery

When using an xquery script in WSO2 ESB I am getting the following error.

```
[2015-06-05 14:28:55,983]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  ERROR_DETAIL :` org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unable to execute the query
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.handleException(XQueryMediator.java:649)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.mediate(XQueryMediator.java:130)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
                at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LoopBackMediator.mediate(LoopBackMediator.java:42)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
                at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
                at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
                at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
                at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error during the querying Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.handleException(XQueryMediator.java:649)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.performQuery(XQueryMediator.java:414)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.mediate(XQueryMediator.java:123)
                ... 16 more
        Caused by: javax.xml.xquery.XQException: Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
                at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.newXQException(SaxonXQConnection.java:195)
                at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.prepareExpression(SaxonXQConnection.java:143)
                at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.prepareExpression(SaxonXQConnection.java:128)
                at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.performQuery(XQueryMediator.java:284)


 ... 17 more
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
        at net.sf.saxon.query.QueryParser.grumble(QueryParser.java:417)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.grumble(ExpressionParser.java:212)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.grumble(ExpressionParser.java:199)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseBasicStep(ExpressionParser.java:1839)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseStepExpression(ExpressionParser.java:1654)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseRelativePath(ExpressionParser.java:1573)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parsePathExpression(ExpressionParser.java:1557)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseUnaryExpression(ExpressionParser.java:1447)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExprSingle(ExpressionParser.java:517)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionParser.parseExpression(ExpressionParser.java:455)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.QueryParser.parseQuery(QueryParser.java:329)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.QueryParser.makeXQueryExpression(QueryParser.java:140)
        at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:536)
        at net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.prepareExpression(SaxonXQConnection.java:138)
        ... 19 more

    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,120]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unable to execute the query
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,120]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_FungusTransform} -  ERROR_CODE : 0 ERROR_MESSAGE : Unable to execute the query
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,120]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  FaultHandler : org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler@7803a7ad
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,124]  WARN {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Executing fault handler mediator : fault
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,125]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_FungusTransform} -  Executing fault sequence mediator : fault
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,126]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Start : Sequence <fault>
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,166]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Sequence <SequenceMediator> :: mediate()
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,166]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Mediation started from mediator position : 0
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,166]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Start : Log mediator
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,166]  INFO {SERVICE_LOGGER.PX_FungusTransform} -  To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:
    uuid:ce9a630d-7b46-4433-bc7a-65408c980461, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE
    = Unable to execute the query , Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/s
    oap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><fungi><fungus><name>Goldcap</name><cap>Yellow, White and Pearlescent</cap><stem>None</stem><gill>Smooth</gill><
    toxin>Mercury comparable to Tuna/lb</toxin></fungus><fungus><name>Silvercap</name><cap>Blue, White and Pearlescent</cap><stem>Long and thin<
    /stem><gill>Rough</gill><toxin>None</toxin></fungus></fungi></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,180]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:ce9a630d-7b46-44
    33-bc7a-65408c980461, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unable to execute t
    he query , Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapen
    v:Body><fungi><fungus><name>Goldcap</name><cap>Yellow, White and Pearlescent</cap><stem>None</stem><gill>Smooth</gill><toxin>Mercury compara
    ble to Tuna/lb</toxin></fungus><fungus><name>Silvercap</name><cap>Blue, White and Pearlescent</cap><stem>Long and thin</stem><gill>Rough</gi
    ll><toxin>None</toxin></fungus></fungi></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,202]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  End : Log mediator
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,202]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  Start : Drop mediator
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,202]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  End : Drop mediator
    [2015-06-05 14:28:56,202]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} -  End : Sequence <fault>
```

The xquery file (also tried with  as the first line.)

```
<x><![CDATA[
    declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope";
    declare variable $payload as element() external;

    for $fungus in $payload/fungus
    return {$fungus/name};
]]></x>
```

and the proxy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="PX_FungusTransform"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <loopback/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" category="TRACE"/>
         <xquery key="xquery_fungusTransform">
            <variable name="payload" type="ELEMENT"/>
         </xquery>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

When researching this issue I found this
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-3081

I was able to duplicate the issue outlined on my system where attempting to add a Local Entry containing the XQuery file listed above resulted in the "`<![CData[`" and "`]]>`" being arbitrarily removed. I'm assuming that the problem I'm encountering and this issue are connected (or that there was a change in xml parsers.)

Is there a work around? or a patch?

Comment: I abandoned trying to use the XQuery mediator in WSO2 in favor of using the Script Mediator (JS.)

Answer (score 0):

Your XQuery is invalid, you don't need the trailing semi-colon and you don't need the CDATA section. Also your prolog must come before your query. Try rewriting it to this:

```
declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope";
declare variable $payload as element() external;

<x>
{
    for $fungus in $payload/fungus
    return
        $fungus/name
}
</x>
```

Also if your XML is in a namespace then you need to add the namespace prefix to the element names in your XPaths.

Comment: Changed the xquery file to match what you have, and it's not working. It's returning 

Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error during the querying Unexpected token "{" in path expression
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.xquery.XQueryMediator.handleException(XQueryMediator.java:649)

Comment: The code I shared is valid XQuery code, so perhaps your processor imposes some limitations?

Comment: When using an xquery script in WSO2 ESB I am getting the following error.